# Google Spreadsheets API via Ruby

Tags: ruby, gdata-api, google-sheets

I wrote a script here to access a Google Spreadsheet by name using Ruby:
http://gist.github.com/606488

I'm trying to use `gdata` as per the instuctions here:
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html

How come I'm getting a 401 error "Token invalid" when using the `gdata` gem?

It works fine when I use the methods described here:
http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/articles/using_ruby.html,
but I figured I should go by the former doc since it's newer & simpler

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Check out the google-spreadsheets-ruby gem:

http://gimite.net/gimite/rubymess/google-spreadsheet-ruby/

Comment: Is it thread safe? Have you seen thread-safe example of it somewhere?